# Ajax call on an external json object within a php file

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, ajax

I'm trying to parse a json file within an external php file with ajax from a different server (technically the same provider but I don't think it really matters).

Anyway my code in my wordpress website to create a json file from my database is the following:

```
        <pre>
            <?php


            global $wpdb;
            if(!isset($wpdb))
            {
                require_once('wp-config.php');
                require_once('wp-includes/wp-db.php');
            }

            $result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM " . $table_prefix . "some_row" );
            print_r(json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));
            ?>
        </pre>
```

The url of this file is (example) http://somewebsite.com/phpjson.php.

I'm calling from the other url (example) http://app.someotherwebsite.com in this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://somewebsite.com/phpjson.php",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "JSON",
                cache: false,
                success: function(markers) {
                   $.each(markers,function(i, val){
                   //do something
              }
    });
});
```

For some reason, I'm not able to call the file probably because of the format of for something else, any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues:

1. The result of `json_encode()` is a string, not an array. So instead of using `print_r()` you should be using `echo` or `print`.
2. Wrapping the JSON in `<pre>` tags invalidates the JSON, so it can't be parsed by jQuery. You should remove the `<pre>`/`</pre>` tags.
3. For best results, make sure you set a content-type header before outputting the JSON data: `header('Content-Type: application/json');`.

Try that and let us know if it solves the problem.

Comment: Thank you! I've never understood a thing. Where should I put a header like that header('Content-Type: application/json');.? Within the php script or in the .htaccess file? At the very beggining? Before the php tag?

Comment: `header()` is a PHP function, so it must be in the PHP file, somewhere between `<?php` and `?>`. Since the `header()` function tells the browser what to expect, it must be called **before** you send any output (you will get a `headers already sent` warning otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

Check documentation : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

> *crossDomain (default: false for same-domain requests, true for cross-domain requests)*
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> If you wish to force a crossDomain request (such as JSONP) on the same
>   domain, set the value of crossDomain to true. This allows, for
>   example, server-side redirection to another domain. (version added:
>   1.5)